# Inserting list ids in the same search input field in jQuery

Tags: jquery

On keyword input, list of items is fetched from the database and I need to insert the id of these items in the same input field (in the keyword input form) on clicking the list item. I could reach only as per as inserting the single list id. When multiple list is shown in the result, it insert only the id of first element. If I click on the other list, it doesn't insert their id's except for the first id. .val(cd.id) insert id of only first list not the other items in the list

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
        var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {
            $.post('search.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                $('ul#list').empty()
                $.each(data, function(ab,cd) {
                $("ul#list").append('<li> ' + cd.title + '</li>').click(function (){
              $('#keyword').val(cd.id);
                });
            });
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

search.php for database request codes. 
  HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword">

<ul id="list">
    List of rows item fetched from database on input keyword
 </ul>
```

Comment: Do you think anyone out here can reproduce the issue with this data? You might wanna consider adding sample `data` to test.

Comment: You are looping with each but are overwriting the keyword value each time you run $('#keyword').val(cd.id);

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Not sure what you said but if you want to see in live page see here https://websiteclubs.xyz/odd/test/index.html  .. type " bar" in the field, and click on any list shown.. It will insert id of first list irrespective of selection from the list.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, the question is pretty clear. All I am saying is that you need to paste the sample `data` in your question so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `each`, just populate `ul` as follows,

```
$.each(data, function(ab,cd) {
    $("#list").append('<li id="'+ cd.id +'"> ' + cd.title+ '</li>');
});
```

And write click event separately as follows,

```
$('#list').on('click','li',function(){
  $('#keyword').val(this.id);
});
```

Comment: @JayprakashSharma what else you need? I don't understand your question properly.

Comment: I need to insert the id of each list as shown in the keyword result in to the same input field. See here websiteclubs.xyz/odd/test/index.html type 'bar'.. When you click any list in the result, it insert all the ids of all the result. Need individual ids to insert

Comment: @JayprakashSharma what you mean by multiple list.

Comment: Based on search query it will show all the matched keyword list in the result. Each result item has their own ids. On clicking any list item, it should insert their respective ids in the same input field (i.e keyword input field). I am repeating your last line in original answer:  "$('#keyword').val(cd.id); will always replace the old value with new value".. That's exactly what I want. But in my case, old value is not being replaced by new ids on clicking the other items in the list.

Comment: For eg. if you visit this link https://websiteclubs.xyz/odd/test/index.html   and type "bar". There will be 3 result item.. Try clicking on any item, it will insert only the id of first item.

Comment: Ok I got it. So you need the selected list item id to be displayed on the keyword field. right?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! only one id at a time no combined ids

Comment: I have posted the complete jQuery code I'm using right now. Check at the top.